# Mediaelement.js Firefox Flash Plugin - Controls don't load

Tags: mediaelement.js

If I supply only an mp3 file on an audio element, Firefox should fall back to a flash plugin (as on the MediaElement.js homepage). However in my case the MediaElement wrapper is created, the embed plugin is created, but no controls are added (e.g. play/pause). I've spent a lot of time trying to debug this but I haven't been able to identify where things go wrong. There is no error in the console and the error callback is not fired. Any ideas on what I could try next would be much appreciated!

UPDATE - SOLVED:
argh! There was a problem with the path to the flashmediaelement.swf file. I had to use an absolute URL. For example:

```
$('audio').mediaelementplayer({
        plugins:['flash'], pluginPath:'http://www.mysite.com/path/to/libs/mediaelement/'});
```

Comment: Can you show some code of what you have tried ?